# C#: Update Item value in List<of T>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm looking for a way to update an Element in a List without enumerating it on my own.

I got the Class MyProjects which hold a List named Projects.

I want to find the MyProjects.Projects-Class, where a member property of Class1 (Name) equals the Value "Overhead".

What works:

```
foreach (Project prj in MyProjects.Projects) {
    if (prj.Name == "Overhead")
        prj.IsActive = true;
};
```

I, however, try to do the same by using Linq, but failed in writing it as one line. Is this even possible? The reason why I don't like to iterate in the way above is that I already iterate the whole list in this codeblock and think, that there might be a more beautiful way :)

Comment: Minor note: you have an empty statement after your foreach loop. Is that in your real code? It doesn't do any harm, but it looks a little odd.

Comment: The Q in Linq stand for query - so it's not really intended for modifying existing data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't try to get everything down to one line - just as brief as is readable. In this case, you can use:

```
foreach (var project in MyProjects.Projects.Where(p => p.Name == "Overhead"))
{
    project.IsActive = true;
}
```

That's using LINQ for the *querying* part, which is appropriate as that's what the Q of LINQ stands for. I'd strongly urge you *not* to mutate items within LINQ calls in the way that Mayank's answer does though. It's error-prone (as evidenced by the original answer not working) and against the spirit of LINQ.

That's about as readable as it gets, IMO. It does exactly the same thing as the original code, mind you - you can't avoid *something* iterating over every item in the list, if every item *might* be one you want to update.

EDIT: Just for laughs, if you *really, really* wanted to do it in pretty minimal code, you could use:

```
// DON'T USE THIS!
MyProjects.Project.Count(p => p.Name == "Overhead" && (p.IsActive = true));
```

Here we use the fact that `&&` is short-circuiting to avoid evaluating the assignment (`p.IsActive = true`) unless the condition is matched. It's handy that we're assigning a `bool` value to a property, as that means we don't need to do anything else to make it a valid second operand for the `&&` operator. We use `Count()` to fully evaluate the result without creating any additional lists etc - and we use the version with a predicate to avoid even needing a `Where` call, which a previous version did. (`LastOrDefault` would work too.) But it's all a horrible abuse, and should never appear in any real code.

Comment: Ok, if it's not even designed for it, it won't make any sense to use it therefore. I'm still learning (I started C# last Friday) and try to do my best :)

Comment: @AllDayPiano: Note that my answer is still using LINQ - but only for the appropriate part. I think this code using `Where` is more pleasant than using an `if` in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with a way to get it down to one line, without abusing LINQ, since I'm only using it for the querying part (filter), and using a custom extension method to perform the property setting action. You're still going to enumerate the items (you have to) but you can hide that away in the extension method. I suspect that you didn't really care whether you enumerated the item or not, you just didn't like the amount of visible space a `foreach` loop would take up in your main code.

Use this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SetProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        action.Invoke(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This allows you to get it down to one readable line.

```
Projects.Where(p => p.Name == "Overhead").SetProperty(p => p.IsActive = true);
```

Complete test program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Projects = new List<Project>() {
                new Project() { Name="Overhead", IsActive=false },
                new Project() { Name="Nadfadfs", IsActive=false },
                new Project() { Name="Overhead", IsActive=false },
                new Project() { Name="dasfasdf", IsActive=false }
            };
            PrintProjectList(Projects);
            Console.WriteLine("--Setting property--");
            Projects.Where(p => p.Name == "Overhead").SetProperty(p => p.IsActive = true);
            PrintProjectList(Projects);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void PrintProjectList(IEnumerable<Project> projects)
        {
            foreach(var p in projects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {p.Name} IsActive: {p.IsActive}");
            }
        }
    }

    class Project
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> SetProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                action.Invoke(item);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Name: Overhead IsActive: False
>
> Name: Nadfadfs IsActive: False
>
> Name: Overhead IsActive: False
>
> Name: dasfasdf IsActive: False
>
> --Setting Property--
>
> Name: Overhead IsActive: True
>
> Name: Overhead IsActive: False
>
> Name: Overhead IsActive: True
>
> Name: Overhead IsActive: False

---

It turns out that my `SetProperty` function is very similar to the [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) that's already built into the framework. The main difference being that mine can operate on any `IEnumerable<T>`. That syntax is loved by some, and hated by others, for reasons that Eric Lippert pointed out on [his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) (Thanks to Jon Skeet for pointing this out). Also, see [this discussion](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/01/31/foreach.aspx) by the Microsoft team. I'll leave it to you to draw your own conclusion.

On a side note, calling it `SetProperty` is kind of inaccurate, because you could do any action on the items in the collection. You could call it `ForEach`, but that clashes with the framework. Not positive what I'd call it, but perhaps `PerformAction`.

Comment: Rather than calling it `SetProperty` I'd probably call it `ForEach` - at which point it's an extension method which exists in many places. I'm still not keen, for the reasons Eric talks about here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx But yes, it's a lot better than the "pure LINQ" abuse.

Comment: Looks great. It's a little more code, but it helps me understanding C# :)

Answer (score -3):

Following Linq statement should work

```
MyProjects.Projects.Where(p => p.Name == "Overhead")
.Select(x => {x.IsActive = true; return x;})
.ToList();
```

As per comments from @JonSkeet, @TimSchmelter and @LeandroSoares, above code is really bad idea. Here are some reasons

1. Calling `.ToList()` causes whole lazy collection to be executed and loaded in the memory.
2. Code above isn't very readable and hard to maintain.
3. Code above is abusing the API as it is forcing the API to do things which it is not designed for.

Comment: You need to consume the lazy collection for it to execute.

Comment: That won't do anything, due to lazy evaluation. Nothing will iterate over the  result, so it will never do any filtering or mutating. LINQ is designed for the querying part..

Comment: Yes, but wasteful - and now you're calling `ToList()` *twice* for no obvious reason. To me, this is both less efficient *and* less readable than a simple foreach loop. LINQ is for querying, not updating - the fact that you *can* abuse it like this doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @JonSkeet understood.

Comment: You know that `ToList` enumerates all items and adds them to a new list? Do you think that this is needed here? Would you do that also if LINQ wouldn't exist?

Comment: I agree with @Jon Skeet, his option is way more readable. However i don't consider that this is wrong. I would only remove the last `.ToList()`, you can still iterate through an enumerable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I also know that it's not the best thing to do, but I am just giving the person what he's asking. My mistake is that I didn't explain the pitfalls that come with it.

Comment: @LeandroSoares: It's not "wrong" in that it will work - but it's code that makes me wince and I would certainly reject in code review, as abusing an API, being hard to read, and performing badly. As such, I think it's unhelpful. It's a bit like presenting a "sort" algorithm of "shuffle, see if it's sorted, and repeat if not"... yes, it'll work, but it's a really bad idea.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, the @Jon Skeet option (without `.ToList()`) still calls all the items through the foreach. `.ToList()` it's a good option if you are trying to update some value inside a foreign key property (lazy loading), if you don't use `.ToList()` it will give you an exception.

Comment: @LeandroSoares: Yes, my option iterates through all the items, once. The option presented here creates two lists *for no reason* and abuses LINQ to do so. It would be *better* if it used `Count()` instead of `ToList`, but it would still be an abuse IMO.

Comment: @LeandroSoares: abusing `ToList` is certainly not a good idea and the fact that it works or prevents exceptions doesn't mean that you should use it. You are referring to Linq2Sql or Linq2Entities . That's a different topic. But using `ToList` there has an even greater impact since you're basically loading the whole database into memory just to be able to update a value.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, That's why i said before "remove the last .ToList(), you can still iterate through an enumerable". But i see your point, it's less readable and more error catching this way.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, i'm referring LinqToSql

Comment: @LeandroSoares: Whereas this question *isn't* referring to LINQ to SQL. It's referring to `List<T>` as per the title. And if you remove the `ToList` calls and add a `foreach` over the query, you're putting all the side-effects into evaluating the sequence you iterate over, with an empty body - horrid! There's simply no good reason to do this.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, You don't load all the database, just the table you are calling (with the where clauses), like you do in your foreach.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, If you put a `ToList` after your `Where` would it be slower?

Comment: @LeandroSoares: In my answer? Yes, it would. It would create a new list for no reason. And again, any talk of databases is irrelevant to this question, which *starts* with a `List<T>`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, sorry i didn't see it wasn't LinqToSql

Comment: For anyone still reading these comments, I've updated my answer to include a more efficient and shorter abuse of LINQ. You know, if you really hate whoever's maintaining your code...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, does help learn more when you explain stuff. I have learned a lot just by giving a bad answer :)